# Remove first \tcbline in tcolorbox environment if there is no preceding text

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm trying to define my own proof environment where I have division of the proof into steps. I use `tcolorbox` to wrap the `proof` environment, and the steps are separated with `\tcbline*`. However, before that, I also redefine the `proof` environment to get rid of the "Proof:" prefix.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

% Renew proof environment to avoid "Proof." at the start.
\renewenvironment{proof}{\unskip\ignorespaces}{\hfill \qedsymbol}

% Creates a heading for a step of a proof.
\NewDocumentCommand{\proofpart}{m}{\tcbline*\noindent\textbf{#1}\vspace{0.25em}\newline}

% Wrap the proof environment in a tcolorbox.
\tcolorboxenvironment{proof}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
\proofpart{First (should not have line above)}
abc
\proofpart{Second (should have line above)}
abc
\proofpart{Third (should have line above)}
abc
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

This looks like this:

[image]

I'd like the first `\tcbline*` to not be shown in case there is no preceding text before it. Can this be achieved somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An attempt which skips the `\tcbline*` in `\proofpart` if the first paragraph in upper part has not been started yet.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newif\ifmytcbupperstarted
\tcbsetforeverylayer{
  code={\mytcbupperstartedfalse},
  before upper pre={\AddToHookNext{para/begin}{\mytcbupperstartedtrue}}
}

% Renew proof environment to avoid "Proof." at the start.
\renewenvironment{proof}{\unskip\ignorespaces}{\hfill \qedsymbol}

% Creates a heading for a step of a proof.
\NewDocumentCommand{\proofpart}{m}{%
  \ifmytcbupperstarted\tcbline*\fi
  \noindent\textbf{#1}\vspace{0.25em}\newline}

% Wrap the proof environment in a tcolorbox.
\tcolorboxenvironment{proof}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
\proofpart{First (should not have line above)}
abc
\proofpart{Second (should have line above)}
abc
\proofpart{Third (should have line above)}
abc
\end{proof}

\begin{tcolorbox}
  \ifmytcbupperstarted\tcbline\fi
  layer 1
  \tcbline
  layer 1
  \begin{tcolorbox}
    \ifmytcbupperstarted\tcbline\fi
    layer 2
    \tcbline
    layer 2
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: now the first \proofpart doesn't produce a separation line]

[image: and it works for tcolorboxes on layer 2 and higher]

The original version

```tex
\tcbset{before upper pre={\AddToHookNext{para/begin}{\mytcbupperstartedtrue}}}
```

only works for outer most `tcolorbox`es. The now revised version also works for nested `tcolorbox`es.

Comment: Seems to work great, thanks!